# Angularjs ui-sref is not working inside uib-accordion-heading

Tags: angularjs, accordion

I have used `<uib-accordion>`. I have used `<a ui-sref>` for `<uib-accordion-group>` and its successfully working. But I want to use `<a ui-sref>` for `<uib-accordion-heading>` also, which is not working now.

Please find below code snippet,

```
<uib-accordion >
    <uib-accordion-group  ng-repeat="name in names" ng-scroll="name in names">
        <uib-accordion-heading >
            <a ui-serf="formname" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true, notify: true}" > {{ names.name }}  </a>
        </uib-accordion-heading>
            <div class="list-group name_list">          
                <a ui-sref="anotherForm" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true, notify: true}" class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="id in names.name" ng-scroll="id in names.name" ng-model="namelist" > {{ name.first }}  </a>
            </div>
    </uib-accordion-group>
</uib-accordion>
```

Comment: could you provide plunkr/fiddle in question itself, by reproducing it.

Comment: I see `ui-serf`, not `ui-sref`...

Comment: @Pevara nice catch.... :D

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/Sd5psPZvugunjpBGzjst?p=preview